# BASH convert a text file line by line into variables

Tags: linux, bash, variables, text

I want to make a script for an automated setup for a multiseat system. First action is

`lspci | grep -i 'vga\|graphic' | cut -b 1-7 > text.txt`

Now i want to put the two lines of the file into variables. My dowdy solution was this:

```
VAR1=$(head -n 1 text.txt)
VAR2=$(tail -n 1 text.txt)
```

It also works, however, there's probably a better solution to convert a text file line by line into variables.

Comment: How will the variables be used once you have extracted them?

Comment: How many lines are you wanting to process. This could get unwieldy because the command line doesn't have arrays, so each variable will have to be subscripted. Nasty.

Comment: I will use them with sed in the xorg configuration file. Actually there are only two lines, but otherwise the script would fail. it also works with head/tail, but it's not that elegant... Something like VAR1=firstlineoffile, VAR2=secondlineoffile and so on

Comment: One issue you will run into is the number of lines returned is system/controller dependent. Additionally, the `slot` information for the same device may be contained on multiple lines identifying individual `function` capabilities the controller. [i.e. in `([domain:]bus:device.function) format]` If you are concerned only about the `slot` information and `description` simply read the complete line and use `parameter expansion/substring extraction` to separate the needed parts. (i.e. `slot=${line%% *}` and `desc=${line#* }` No need to spawn multiple shells calling 3rd party apps when bash works

Answer (score 1):

The following should achieve exactly what you're doing, without the use of a temporary file

```
#!/bin/bash

{ read -r var1 _ && read -r var2 _; } < <(lspci | grep -i 'vga\|graphics')
```

Now, if you have several lines from `lspci | grep -i 'vga\|graphics'` (or just one, or none), you might want something more general, i.e., put the results in an array:

```
#!/bin/bash

var=()
while read -r f _; do var+=( "$f" ); done < <(lspci | grep -i 'vga\|graphics')
# display the content of var
declare -p var
```

If you have a recent version of Bash, and you love `mapfile` and `awk` (but who doesn't?), you could also do something like this:

```
#!/bin/bash

mapfile -t var < <(lspci | awk 'tolower($0) ~ /var|graphics/ { print $1 }')
# display the content of var
declare -p var
```

For a Pure Bash possibility (except for `lspci`, of course):

```
#!/bin/bash

shopt -s  extglob

var=()
while read -r v rest; do
    [[ ${rest,,} = *@(vga|graphics)* ]] && var+=( "$v" )
done < <(lspci)
# display var
declare -p var
```

This uses:

- Lower case conversion of `rest` with `${rest,,}`
- [Pattern matching and extended globs](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Pattern-Matching) with `*@(vga|graphics)*` (to avoid regular expressions altogether).

Answer (score 0):

If you can format your text file into name value pairs, you could use bash [associative arrays](http://www.linuxjournal.com/content/bash-associative-arrays) to store and reference each item. Note in this code `=` is used as the delimiter to separate the name value pair.

```
#read in fast config (name value pair file)
 declare -A MYMAP
 while read item; do

    NAME=$(cut -d "=" -f1 <<<"$item")
    VALUE=$(cut -d "=" -f2 <<<"$item")
    MYMAP["$NAME"]="$VALUE"

 done <./config_file.txt

 #size of map
 MYMAP_N=${#MYMAP[@]}

 #make a list of keys
 KEYS=("${!MYMAP[@]}")

 #dereference map
 SELECTION="${MYMAP["my_first_key"]}"
```

Comment: Why bother using an associative array when normal shell variables will work? Or if the source file is under careful control just make it valid shell assignments and source it.

Comment: "convert a text file line by line into variables"... who knows how he intends to use the variables. i see that he now states he only had 2 variables, but my solution is general.

Comment: So are both of my suggestions unless any of the keys are not valid shell identifiers. My point is that shell variables are already a key=value store you don't need to introduce associative arrays (and a bash 4+ requirement) to have access to one of those.

Answer (score 0):

If the values do not contain spaces, in `bash` using the array variable:

```
declare -a vars
eval "vars=(`echo line1; echo line2`)"   # the `echo ...` simulates your command
echo number of values: ${#vars[@]}
for ((I = 0; I < ${#vars[@]}; ++I )); do
    echo value \#$I is ${vars[$I]}
done
echo all values : ${vars[*]}
```

The trick is to generate the statement initializing the array with the values, and then `eval` it.

If the values have spaces/special characters, then escaping/quoting might be necessary.

Comment: Don't use `eval`; you can use a loop to add lines one-by-one to the array.

Comment: @chepner, the loop variant would be redundant, since it is already demonstrated (with the associative array) in the answer by ldgorman.

Comment: My point is, don't use `eval` when there is an alternative. In general, it's not safe, and using it when it's not necessary is a bad habit to get into.

Answer (score 0):

`read VAR1 VAR2 < <(sed -n '1p;$p' myfile | tr '\n' ' ')`

This ought to do what you need it uses process substitution to print the lines you want and then redirects them to the variables, if you want different lines just build this statement as you need with a for loop putting whatever lines you want if you want them all use wc to count the lines, then build VAR1 .. VAR[n] and sed -n '1p;2p;3p..[n]p' and you then can eval the built statement.